# Animate number counter on custom view with for loop in onDraw method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-custom-view

I'm confused if this is even the right way to do. Please correct me. So basically i have a text drawn in my custom view with `canvas.drawText` method. The text is a number (amount). I'm trying to make the text animate to another number (example: 100 => 800) when an event occurs.

I'm aware that this can be done with a for loop counter in `onDraw` method and calling `canvas.drawText` and `invalidate()` until it reaches the final number. But my app is stuck.

**UPDATED code:**

I have updated the code. Now the app doesn't get stuck (as per Simon's advice). But now it just draws all the numbers at one go (1-99). **I dont know how to slow down the loop**.

```
public class CustomView extends View implements OnTouchListener{

   private Canvas main_canvas;

   //...Other codes like, initialization, paint etc!...//

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      main_canvas = canvas;
   }

   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      switch(event.getAction()){
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      //...Some action...//
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      //...Some action...//
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      runTextAnimation();
      }
   }

   private void runTextAnimation() {

        for(int i=1; i < 100; i++){
            main_canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(i), getMeasuredWidth()/2, 100, amountPaint);
            invalidate();
        }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using a **Runnable** and using `postDelayed` for queueing the message for some milliseconds. Though I have to thank Simon for narrowing my search and thoughts. Below is the snippet. Hope this could help someone. Cheers.

```
    private Handler mHandler;
    private int i;

    mHandler.post(mUpdate); //call this to run

    private Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {
               public void run() {

                main_canvas.drawText("Secret Text"+i, getMeasuredWidth()/2, 50, textPaint);

                i++; // incrementing the value

                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 60);
                invalidate();
                }
        };
```

BTW the snippet above is an infinity counter, watchout to stop it at sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use invalidate() in onDraw()!

invalidate() causes onDraw() to be called, then you invalidate() which causes onDraw() to be called, then you invalidate() - you get the idea.  The loop should be outside onDraw() and you use invalidate to update the view.  But be careful, if your loop is too quick, you might not see all updates since updates are queued.

To sleep the thread for a while:

```
Thread.sleep(50);
```

This sleeps for 50 milliseconds.  Try it, but I think using a Runnable on the UI thread will be the better solution.

Comment: Thanks ill try that, is there a way to slow down the loop for some micro second?

Comment: You could sleep() for a while but personally, if I find myself contemplating sleep(), it's a prompt for me to think about alternatives.

Comment: Dear simon, As you said, It's the correct approach to call `invalidate()` outside `onDraw()`. That's working and app dosn't get stuck. But I'm confused with the loop and running it with a thread. Can you please update some hint's or code? Basically I'm running this loop after on `onTouch` event `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is triggered. Hope I'm clear in my explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code - i.e. the loop and how it gets called.  Why are you using a separate thread?  My guess is that you're just incrementing an integer and updating your view.  I can't see anything to gain by starting another thread.

Comment: I've updated my answer but, the need to use sleep() often indicates a bad design.  Let me know if it works, then we can think of a different approach?